# Сохранение дополнительной информации в машине состояний Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет. Такая ситуация...

У меня есть в коде **FSMContext**, который я запускаю, чтобы **пользователь ввел** (допустим) **новое** имя пользователя. Когда запускается машина состояний (после ввода текста пользователем), происходит запуск новой функции типа `@dp.message_handler(state=...)`
После всего этого мне нужна информация о его старом имени пользователя, которую я должен бы был брать из json файла, но эту информацию негде сохранить, потому что когда пользователь вводит что-то, message занят этим сообщением, а доп переменные не переносятся в эту функцию.
По итогу... У меня есть новое имя, а какому пользователю изменить имя я не знаю (не говорите что можно посмотреть по message.chat.id или message.chat.username, потому что это пример и мне нужно изменить инфу, которая храниться в файле 1 пользователя в каком либо массиве внутри его данных).

По итогу поврос. Как передать какую-либо другую информацию вместе с машиной состояний?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А что мешает передать в машину состоянии старое значение и новое? Там же хранится всё как в обычном словаре "ключ-значение"

Comment: согласен с комментарием выше